# Gcc default version crashes

Tags: c

I working on open source GHDL project for my project purpose installed `ghdl-0.29-2.143svn.4.fc16.src.rpm` consisting of *ghdl 0.29* and *gcc 4.3.4* through `rpm -i` and `rpmbuild -ba` command successfully.

In ghdl folder, I edited one ada program then I did `make` and `make install` : no errors but it creates problem changes in gcc version 4.6.3 (default) to 4.3.4 and no gcc program execution gave error:

```
error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details." 
In config.log file /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks in advance

Regards
Raghu

Comment: improve your question by detailing the error you are getting.

Comment: I edited for better readability, but your sentence in the middle does not make much sense for me currently

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reinstalling glibc? That might work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.After reinstall also same problem,simple c program not executing gave below error  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtbegin.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It is unable to find the libgcc library path. Have look at the discussion here : [link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgcc_s-919330/)

Comment: And also, as mentioned [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=271556) , see if you have all the required packages installed e.g. glibc-common glibc-devel @Ragu